# Voltage calculation from RF rigid line directional wattmeter

Tags: voltage, power, rf

I have a question about voltage calculation from RF rigid line directional wattmeter.

I have a device like below:

[image]

We tested it under 1kW coming from transmitter.

Schema like this:

|| Transmitter(1kW) >> RF rigid line directional wattmeter (picture is in above) >> Bird 43 model wattmeter >> 1kW dummy load ||

[image]

We took DC voltages from BNC mounted connectors like image 2.

While testing we took some voltage examples at 500W and 1kW with some elements like in the table.

[image]

I found a calculation  from Bird's documents as in the image 4 but I don't understand, still , how to I calculate RF power to DC voltage as to changing elements and its materials.

[image]

So my question again, how to calculate manually voltage coming from RF rigid line directional wattmeter?

If you have any questions, I will be here.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of that description it says that the rf is rectified, filtered and displayed on a meter.  The diode that does the rectifying is inside your directional coupler somewhere.  What that does is introduce some non-linearity, making the DC voltage out not exactly proportional to the RF voltage or to the RF power.  Especially when the DC voltage is low.  At higher DC voltages the voltage out is roughly proportional to the RF voltage.  At lower voltages people like to say you're in the "square law" region and the voltage is roughly proportional to the power.  I've never found either approach very accurate. Usually the meter scale on the Bird wattmeter has the calibration built into it.
Probably the best thing to do is get out some software like Matlab or python (or maybe Excel if you're of that persuasion) and take your calibration data and fit a polynomial or a spline to the power vs DC voltage for each of your plug-in elements.  It all depends on how accurate you want to be.
Note that your calibration depends on what load resistance you have on your DC output.  If you plan on putting the DC voltage on an oscilloscope and you want good time resolution then you'll want to put a fairly low load resistance on it, and you'll need to do your calibration with that load present.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We tried before by saving voltage values as to power values. And as you said we obtanied a polinomal function, then. But in that,there was some deviations up to 10W as to real value. So we wanted to try  if any voltage calculation or formulas by asking here and Bird. And yesterday Bird give me an answer like that : **The 500B1 is a 500W, 100uA element used in a 1-5/8" line section.  It looks at a 3k ohm meter and at full scale 300mV will = 500W.** . I will ask again them if there any information for other elements, too.

Comment: If you ever want to escape the diode non-linearity you can find a directional coupler that puts out an RF signal, then build a circuit using an RF detector chip such as the AD8361, which will put out a DC voltage proportional to the RF power.

Comment: I will examine AD8361 and I saw AD8307 used for power meter applications, also.